# Python Flask Function return web page to request and update password in Mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

In my function that enables a reset password (token) link...
I need to display a web page/form that I can use to take user password, generate the password hash using bcrypt, then find and update the password in MongoDB.

My main issue is displaying the web page/form in the function. I get server error at line 5

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, json, url_for, render_template, flash
from flask_mail import Mail, Message
from itsdangerous import URLSafeTimedSerializer, SignatureExpired
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt 


@app.route('/users/reset_password', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def reset_password():
    users = mongo.db.users
    email = request.get_json()['email']
    user_exist = users.find_one({'email': email})

    if user_exist:
        token = s.dumps(email, salt='reset-password-salt')
        msg = Message('Password Reset', sender='admin@exib.com', recipients=[email])
        link = url_for('password_reset', token=token, _external=True)
        msg.body = 'Your password reset link is {}'.format(link)
        mail.send(msg)
        result = jsonify({'message': 'password reset link has been sent to your email'})
    else: 
        result = jsonify({'message': 'this user does not exist'}), 400
    return result

@app.route('/users/password_reset/<token>')
def password_reset(token):
    try:
        email = s.loads(token, salt='reset-password-salt', max_age=3600)
        users = mongo.db.users
        password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(request.form['password']).decode('utf-8')# SERVER ERROR HERE
        users.find_one_and_update(
            {'email': email},
            {'$set':
                {'password': password}
            },upsert=False
        )
        ## I want to display the webform somewhere here to take just 'password' ##
    except SignatureExpired:
        return '<h1>The token is expired!</h1>'
    return passchange.html # '<h1>Password change successful!</h1>'
```

HTML page
`return` passchange.html

```html
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %} 
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <form method=POST action="{{ url_for('password_reset') }}">
                <!-- <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputOldPassword1">Old Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="oldPassword" placeholder="OldPassword">
                </div> -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Change Password</button>
            </form>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post the template code also.

Comment: @ngShravil.py thanks. I'm relatively new to python; I don't really understand what you mean by template but I'm trying to create a password reset API. I added to the code in the post for more clarity. I hope it helps.
The **reset_password():** starts the process of taking the user's email and sending a password reset URL with a token. 
The URL is enabled in **password_reset(token):** but I need a webpage to take the user's new password and save it to the DB within this same function. 
I hope you understand.

Comment: No worries buddy. What I mean is, to post the html part, where this `/users/password_reset/<token>` route or `reset_password()` method is being called/used.

Comment: Oh ok. I'm actually creating this for a react mobile app. It has a reset password screen that takes the user's email for this `reset_password()` function to be called. So I want to redirect the user to a **webpage** (from the URL sent to the user's email - `/users/password_reset/<token>`) to change their password then they can continue on the app.

Comment: Although I also tried to `return` an HTML page at the end of the function to take the **password** but the error still persists at
`password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(request.form['password']).decode('utf-8') # SERVER ERROR HERE`

I update the code posted to show this HTML page. I hope you understand

Comment: First of all, you should not return the hrml page like `return passchange.html`, instead you should do like this: `render_template('passchange.html')`.

Comment: Also could you post what error are you getting?

Comment: And what is `s.dumps` or `s.loads`? Is it JSON lib?

Comment: `s = URLSafeTimedSerializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'])`

Its this `URLSafeTimedSerializer` from `itsdangerous`. I believe it helps to generate the URL link with a token.

Yes you're correct about the `return render_template('passchange.html')`
It was an oversight while editing the code in the post

Comment: werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'password'

`password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(request.form['password']).decode('utf-8')`

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is you are not checking the type of request in `password_reset` method. So every time, irrespective of `GET` or `POST` or any other request type, it's executing the method. But, `request.form` dictionary is available in `POST` request. If you are doing a `GET` request, this will result in an exception.

So, I would suggest you to change it's body to something like below:

```py
@app.route('/users/password_reset/<token>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def password_reset(token):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Do something
    elif request.method == 'GET'
        # Do something
```

Make sure that, when you are retrieving the form value, retrieve it like this `request.form.get('password')`, instead of `request.form['password']`. This is because, sometime the fields might not exist, and it will result in an another exception. So, the former is like, safe way to retrieve the required value.

Also check that, the field's `name` attribute is matching the key, when you are retrieving the value from `request.form`.

Comment: No, I've tried different approaches with the `if` and `elif` but didn't help. It's either it doesn't process that line that causes an error or it processes it and fails again

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out. I had to use Flask forms. I created the form and imported it to the app. I inserted the form in the route `@app.route('/users/password_reset/<token>')` and provisioned it in a .HTML file. This logic enabled me to request a new password while also updating the password in the database all in the same function. Now my code looks like this

```
@app.route('/api/users/password_reset/<token>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def reset_token(token):
    try:
        email = s.loads(token, salt='reset-password-salt', max_age=3600)
        # This payload is decoded and safe
    except BadSignature as e:
        if e.payload is not None:
            try:
                decoded_payload = s.load_payload(e.payload)
            except BadData:
                pass
        flash('The token is expired or invalid.', "danger")
        return redirect(url_for('user_login'))
    form = ResetPasswordForm() # form inserted here
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        hashed_password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(form.password.data).decode('utf-8')
        users = mongo.db.users
        users.find_one_and_update(
            {'email': email},
            {'$set':
                {'password': hashed_password}
            },upsert=False
        )
        flash('Your password has been updated! You are now able to log in.', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('user_login'))
    return render_template('reset_token.html', title='Reset Password', form=form)
```

And this is the created form in form.py

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from flask_wtf.file import FileField, FileAllowed
from wtforms import PasswordField, SubmitField, TextAreaField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length, EqualTo, ValidationError

class ResetPasswordForm(FlaskForm):
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    confirm_password = PasswordField('Confirm Password',
                                     validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('password')])
    submit = SubmitField('Reset Password')
```